# Does La Sagrada Familia light up every night?

Tags: sightseeing, barcelona

For example this [blog post](https://kenkencal.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/la-sagrada-familia-doesnt-light-up-every-night-just-fyi/) says it does not. I can't find a schedule anywhere.

Comment: As far as I know, this is done just in special occasions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La Sagrada Familia can only light up (normal lights, not the lights used for [special events](http://www.digitalavmagazine.com/2012/12/23/la-sagrada-familia-felicita-la-navidad-iluminando-la-fachada-del-nacimiento/)) from Thursday to Saturday between 20:00 and 00:00 due a [decree for light pollution made by the Generalitat](http://www.elperiodico.com/es/noticias/medio-ambiente/decreto-contra-contaminacion-luminica-4458496).

I live 10 min walking from the Sagrada familia, and I can say that even if you go any day (even any from Sunday to Wednesday) at night you will be able to see it very well and take some nice pictures, of course you can have better quality when it's fully lighted.

Comment: "can"?? So do they light it up on those days or not even then?

Comment: I meant that they are only able to light up those day due the decree, and they actually do it